# What are the different ways to create object of a C# class?

Tags: c#, object

I have been asked this question in a job interview, but not sure what are the other options available in C# to create an object of a class. I know the basic way to create an object. For example: I have a class with name 'ClassName', so to create the object, I can use

```cs
ClassName classNameObject = new ClassName();
```

Can someone please tell me what are other ways which can be used to instantiate a class?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe they asked for various syntax differences? Or they wanted to know some conceptional answer like Factory class?

Comment: Different idea: maybe they wanted to know the scope of an instance, eg. you can create an instance in the scope of x?

Comment: Maybe with static initializer and other stuff @Rand Random mentioned

Answer (score 4):

There are several more ways:

1. Create an object using reflection.

   ```
    object classNameObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ClassName));
   ```

   > The `CreateInstance<T>()` generic method is used by compilers to implement the instantiation of types specified by type parameters.

   See more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-MOrhWOoWgOjZfJIlAvNsHw&epi=a1LgFw09t88-MOrhWOoWgOjZfJIlAvNsHw&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=(ir__cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xr139edvoxoy600)(7806)(1243925)(a1LgFw09t88-MOrhWOoWgOjZfJIlAvNsHw)()&irclickid=_cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xr139edvoxoy600&view=net-5.0).
2. Create a reference to an existing object.

   ```
    ClassName classNameObject = new();
    ClassName otherClassNameObject = classNameObject;
   ```
3. Create an object using DI (dependency injection) containers by registering an instance (I will not write here the code as it depends on which DI you use).
4. Create an object with deserializing.

   ```
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new();
    (ClassName)formatter.Deserialize(...);
   ```

You may also use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>`.

5. Create an object with [MemberwiseClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-5.0).

   ```
    ClassName classNameObject = new();
    ClassName otherClassNameObject  = (ClassName) this.MemberwiseClone();
   ```

Note, there are also many ways of different usages of `new` keyword but I didn't mention it here as it is just syntax.

Comment: You can also use `MemberwiseClone`. Syntax variant: `var classNameObject = new ClassName();`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks. I am still editing... Will write it as well.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch to say that creating a reference to an object is the same as "creating an instance of a class". There's also the way of using `new T()` as in `T Create<T>() where T: new()`. But we have no clue if they meant "ways" or "styles" or what exactly

Comment: Create an object by deconstructing an existing object, the possbilities are endless. :) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct

Comment: An explanation with pros and cons of all the **5 ways to create an object to a c# class and when to choose which one**  is available [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-create-an-object-in-c-and-when-to-choose-which-one-4aabea5c3e40)